# Python: cannot change between specific array-numbers

Tags: python, arrays

I would like some help with my program. It is a text-based game, with rooms. 
I want the player to jump between rooms, but only when the player is in certain rooms.

```
#-------------***********GAME************-------------
#This module implements pseudo-random number generators for various    distributions.
from random import randint
import random

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def showInstructions():
   #print a main menu and the commands
   print ("---------------------------")
   print ("***Game***")
   print ("---------------------------")
   print ("Commands:")
   print ("'[direction]'")
   print ("'get [item]'")

def showStatus():
    #print the player's current status
    print ("---------------------------")
    #print the current inventory
    print ("Inventory : " , inventory)
    #print an item if there is one
    print("You are in the " , currentRoom)
    '''
    if "item" in rooms[currentRoom]:
        print( "You see a " + rooms[currentRoom]["item"])
    print ("---------------------------")
'''

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

inventory = []

# A list of rooms
rooms = [
        ["Hall","Discription of the Hall", "0", "6", "3",],
        ["Living Room","Discription of the Living Room", "1", "5", "3", "4"],
        ["Kitchen","Discription of the Kitchen", "0", "2"],
        ["Master Bedroom", "Discription of the Master Bedroom", "0"],
        ["Bedroom", "Discription of the Bedroom", "0"],
        ["Bathroom", "Discription of the Bathroom", "1"],
    ]

currentRoom = rooms[0]

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

showInstructions()
showStatus()

lastCommand = []
commandList = []

numberOfRounds = []

inputList = []

cannotDoThat = ["<<< You cannot do that\n", "<<< Cannot be done\n", "<<<    Impossible\n", "<<< I can't do that\n"]
dontUnderstand = ["<<< I didn't quite get that\n", "<<< I don't understand your    command.\n", "<<< Refrase that command.\n", "<<< What do you mean?\n", "<<< Please    refrase that command.\n", "<<< I do not understand that command.\n", "<<< I don't    know what you mean.\n"]
commands = ["command", "commands", "input list", "inputs", "previous input", "last input", "input", "previous commands", "last command", "turn", "rounds", "round", ]
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
while True:

print "---------------------------"
inputUser = raw_input(">>> ")


lastCommand = inputUser
inputList.append(lastCommand)

# Rooms

if(currentRoom == [0]):
    print currentRoom[0][1]
    print "<<< You have following options:"
    print "<<< Go EAST and enter the Bathroom, or"
    print "<<< Go SOUTH and enter the Living Room, or"
    print "<<< Go WEST and enter the Kitchen."

if(currentRoom == [1]):
    print currentRoom[1][1]
    print "<<< You have following options:"
    print "<<< Go NORTH and enter the Hall, or"
    print "<<< Go EAST and enter the Bedroom, or"
    print "<<< Go WEST and enter the Master Bedroom."

if(currentRoom == [2]):
    print currentRoom[2][1]
    print "<<< You have following options:"
    print "<<< Go EAST and enter the Hall."

if(currentRoom == [3]):
    print currentRoom[3][1]
    print "<<< You have following options:"
    print "<<< Go EAST and enter the Living."

if(currentRoom == [4]):
    print currentRoom[4][1]
    print "<<< You have following options:"
    print "<<< Go WEST and enter the Hall."

if(currentRoom == [5]):
    print currentRoom[5][1]
    print "<<< You have following options:"
    print "<<< Go WEST and enter the Living Room."
```

# Direction Comamnds
   #---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
if(inputUser=="S" or inputUser=="s" or inputUser=="south" or    inputUser=="South" or inputUser=="SOUTH") and (currentRoom==[0]):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)
    currentRoom = [1]
    print "<<< You are now in the " , currentRoom , "\n"
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
elif(inputUser=="N" or inputUser=="n" or inputUser=="north" or inputUser=="North" or inputUser=="NORTH") and (currentRoom == [1]):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)   
    currentRoom = [0]
    print("<<< You are now in the " + currentRoom + "\n")
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
elif(inputUser=="E" or inputUser=="e" or inputUser=="east" or inputUser=="East" or inputUser=="EAST"):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)
    if(currentRoom == [2]):
        currentRoom = [0]   
    elif(currentRoom == [3]):
        currentRoom = [1]
        print("<<< You are now in the " + currentRoom + "\n")
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
elif(inputUser=="w" or inputUser=="W" or inputUser=="west" or inputUser=="West" or inputUser=="WEST"):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)
    if(currentRoom == [4]):
        currentRoom = [0]
    elif(currentRoom == [5]):
        currentRoom = [1]
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Item and inventory

```
elif(inputUser=="inventory"):
    print "<<< Here is a list of your inventory:"
    print "<<< " , inventory
```

# Where am I?

```
elif(inputUser=="Where" or inputUser=="where" or inputUser=="where am i" or inputUser=="Where Am I" or inputUser=="Where?" or inputUser=="Where am i?"):
    print "<<< You are in the ", "'",currentRoom,"'"
```

# Commandlist and round

```
elif(inputUser=="commands" or inputUser=="command" or inputUser=="command list"):
    print "Here is a list of your previous commands:"
    print commandList


elif(inputUser=="last command" or inputUser=="previous command"):

    print "<<< Here is your last command:"
    print "<<< '" ,  commandList[-1] , "'"


elif(inputUser=="round" or inputUser=="rounds" or inputUser=="turn"):
    if commandList == None:
        print "<<< Here is the number of your actionable entries:"
        print "<<< 0"
    else:
        print "<<< Here is the number of your actionable entries:"
        print "<<< " , len(commandList)


elif(inputUser=="input list" or inputUser=="input"):
    print "<<< Here is the list of all user inputs:"
    print "<<< " , inputList


else:

    print (random.choice(dontUnderstand))
```

#-----------------------------***END***----------------------------

I know it isn't complete, but I cannot get further unless I solve this problem.

The problem, I think, is mainly in this part of the code:

```
# Direction Comamnds
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
if(inputUser=="S" or inputUser=="s" or inputUser=="south" or inputUser=="South" or inputUser=="SOUTH") and (currentRoom==[0]):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)
    currentRoom = [1]
    print "<<< You are now in the " , currentRoom , "\n"
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
elif(inputUser=="N" or inputUser=="n" or inputUser=="north" or inputUser=="North" or inputUser=="NORTH") and (currentRoom == [1]):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)   
    currentRoom = [0]
    print("<<< You are now in the " + currentRoom + "\n")
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
elif(inputUser=="E" or inputUser=="e" or inputUser=="east" or inputUser=="East" or inputUser=="EAST"):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)
    if(currentRoom == [2]):
        currentRoom = [0]   
    elif(currentRoom == [3]):
        currentRoom = [1]
        print("<<< You are now in the " + currentRoom + "\n")
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
elif(inputUser=="w" or inputUser=="W" or inputUser=="west" or                               inputUser=="West" or inputUser=="WEST"):
    commandList.append(lastCommand)
    if(currentRoom == [4]):
        currentRoom = [0]
    elif(currentRoom == [5]):
        currentRoom = [1]
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

I want the code to say something like: 
EXAMPLE: If you enter Direction SOUTH, AND you are in the Hall, enter the Living Room.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to review your question to match SO standards, this isn't a [_minimal_ complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you know about dictionaries? You could link all the rooms together with dictionaries and that'd likely be a much more malleable system for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting up a dictionary system instead of just lists. You can then make your set of rooms and give them all a special connections key that will store which rooms you can move into from there.

```
bedroom = {'name':'bedroom','decription':'blah'*4}
hall = {'name':'hall','decription':'blah'*4}
bathroom = {'name':'bathroom','decription':'blah'*4}
kitchen = {'name':'kitchen','decription':'blah'*4}
hall['connections'] = {'SOUTH':bedroom, 'NORTH':bathroom, 'EAST':kitchen}
kitchen['connections'] = {'WEST':hall}
bedroom['connections'] = {'NORTH':hall}
bathroom['connections'] = {'SOUTH':hall}
```

This way, you can check what all the connections are to a given room easily

```
for key in hall['connections']:
    print ("To the {} is the {}".format(key, connection[key]['name']))
```

And it's also a lot easier to edit, rather than rejigging a bunch of different numbers you re-assign text values that aren't dependent on each other.

Comment: I know it is a lot to ask for, but could you help me a little more? I tried to implement it, but it does not work properly.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? I can help but I'll need to know what's going wrong. Also it'll make it easier if I know how familiar you are with dictionaries.